# My Samsung Galaxy E700H Not Detected ! fastboot?

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, android, samsung, heimdall

I am having samsung galaxy e700h and I am interested in installing ubuntu touch via adb, fastboot and ubuntu-device-flash.

But when I run the command fastboot oem unlock, I am always getting the error . I tried almost every thing, havent' got any successful results.

Moreover, heimdall is detecting my device when I run it through heimdall-frontend.

Yes it is rooted. Moreover now I ended up in a Downloading loop... nothing is happening... what to do...

output of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 045: ID 04e8:685d Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II] (Download mode)
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03f0:0a01 Hewlett-Packard ScanJet 2400c
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Can I flash my mobile via heimdall?
I had downloaded image from the below given link:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/xenial-preinstalled-touch-armhf.tar.gz

and I dont' think that this is the flashing image for ubuntu touch.

Answer (score 0):

First boot your device up.

Check if

```
adb devices
```

Lists your device, if it does then:

```
adb reboot fastboot
```

After it boots into fastboot, then:

```
fastboot oem unlock
```

Also, you'll have more luck getting these problems solved at https://xda-developers.com

Comment: Its still showing <waiting for device>

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: Yes it is rooted. Moreover now I ended up in a Downloading loop... nothing is happening... what to do... 

please see the original question. I had edited to display output of lsusb. (above)